# is there an option to make name for axis and also make the color more sharp?

Tags: python, image

[image]

i used the code  here http://www.spectralpython.net/algorithms.html for hyperspectral analysis and i want to make axis and make the color more shape,
also i am trying to make only part of the picture to be visible (where is the plant) and all the background to be hidden.

```
from PIL import Image
from spectral import *
import spectral.io.aviris as aviris
import numpy
img = open_image('VNIR_plot35_2019-06-11_08-33-55.hdr').load()
v=imshow(vi)
#----ndiv algorithem----
```

Answer (score 0):

Using *imshow(vi)* selects 3 bands and displays the same as a color image.
To do the same , make another hypercube for viewing purposes with 3 bands(your discretion):

```
#I have taken bands 1,2 and 3- you can select at your discretion
img2=img[:,:,:3]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#use pyplot's library functions
plt.imshow(img2)
plt.ylabel("y axis")
plt.xlabel("xaxis")
plt.show()
```

What do you mean by making color more sharp?

Comment: i ment so there will be a better contrast.
why should you suggest to take 3 bands?
how to crop only the leaf pixels?
thank you

Comment: For better contrast maybe try histogram equalization on the resultant 2D image.
We need 3 bands to visualise any colour 2D image( 1 band for R,1 for G, and other for B). Maybe try image segmentation methods for only leaf pixels or try any HSI classification method to separate leaf pixels?

Comment: sounds good, i will try to find phyton code for hsi classification. thank you